# react jss how to style custom html tag

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am using `material-ui`, see the sample code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
  },
}));

export default function ContainedButtons() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Button variant="contained">Default</Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Primary
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">
        Secondary
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" disabled>
        Disabled
      </Button>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" href="#contained-buttons">
        Link
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is first time I use `jss`, I try to play around with `& > *` to understand how it works, I guess it is some sort of css selector, but check through the doc [here](https://cssinjs.org/jss-api?v=v10.4.0) and [here](https://cssinjs.org/jss-syntax?v=v10.4.0), I am confused with below:

1. `*` and `>` are valid css selector, I can understand, but what is `&` meaning there?
2. I want to limit the css selector to be applied to button only, should I use `& > button` or `& > Button`? Both are working, but I am confused, in the end, what to be displayed to browser is `button`, so it is better to use `& > button`?

Comment: `&` typically refers to the parent element, and is sometimes used to also bump the specificity of the selector. Why not create a second style key-value pair, i.e. `button: ...` and apply it to the buttons, i.e. `<Button className={classes.button} ...`?

Comment: @DrewReese in that case, I have to add in for all the buttons, but declare on parent node, it is just one enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**: JSS and other third-party React libraries such as styled-components port SCSS (Sass) functionalities to provide extended CSS features for CSS-in-JS.

You have not seen `&` in CSS because it is a SCSS (Sass) feature. Sass is a preprocessor scripting language that extends the normal CSS with more features:

- It allows you to use nesting when styling your components or html elements.
- `&` is the parent selector. It references the HTML element where it is nested.

In this case `&` references `root` since it is directly nested inside it. `& > *` applies the styling to all elements (`*`) that are direct descendants (`>`) of root (`&`).

```scss
root: {
  '& > *': {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  }
}
```

**Example**: `&` can make you life easier, a good example is applying a hover state to a button.

In normal CSS you would do this:

```css
button {
  background-color: tomato;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

With SCSS you could use nesting and the parent selector (`&`) to do this:

```scss
button {
  background-color: tomato;
  &:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

1. Reference: https://cssinjs.org/from-sass-to-cssinjs
2. Reference: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/declarations#nesting
3. Reference: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector
4. Reference: https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#can-i-nest-rules

**Question 2**: In ReactJS components start with an uppercase letter while HTML Elements start with a lowercase letter. So `Button` is a React component and `button` is the vanilla HTML element.

You can create a `Button` component that is made of a `button` with an `img` and a `p` inside.

`& > Button` will select all `Button` react components that are direct descendant of `&` (The value of & depends on the rest of your code, with the information I gave you above you'll be able to figure it out) while `& >` will select all `button` HTML elements that are direct descendants of `&`.

**Example**: Imagine a situation where you have `div` that contains a `Button` React Component (has a button HTML element in its composition) and a `ToggleButton` React Component (has a button HTML element in its composition):

- If you use `& > Button`, you only will select the `button` HTML element in the `Button` that is a direct descendant of the `div` (`&`).
- If you use `& > button`, you only will select the `button` HTML element in `Button` and in `ToggleButton` that are direct descendants of the `div` (`&`).